# OC'ing a Sapphire 7950, problems with memory clock

Tags: memory, bios, time, overclocking

I bought a new rig with sapphire radeon 7950 flex w/ boost. Good scores initially in 3dmark 11, around 7300 stock. Problem is, as soon as i start overclocking, issues arise. the core clock is at 860, but rises to 925 with boost applied in pressured situations. So all the OC tools are showing 925 as base clock for some reason. Ocing the core clock has been no problem though, got up to 1200 pretty stable, but only an incremental increase in 3dmark 11, to 7600 from 7300, which is worrying.

The real trouble starts when i start touching the memory clock. As soon as i touch it even by 1 point up to 1251mhz, the performance goes way down. suddenly i score under 5000 graphics in 3dmark11, no matter if its 1251hz or 1500hz. Ive tried adjusting every other parameter, different tools (sapphiretrixx, catalyst, afterburner) all still the same. Tried upping the power, still same. Where is the issue here?